# Print each word in a separate line from an input string

Tags: c, string, char, printf, scanf

I'm having trouble printing each word in a separate line from an input string in C. The question from the assignment I'm doing states:

> Take a sentence as input and print its words in separate lines.

My Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i;
   char s[100];

   scanf("%s", s);

   for(i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
   {
      printf("%c", s[i]);

      if(s[i]==' ')
      {
         printf("\n");
      }
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are having trouble writing readable code.

Comment: fix your formatting. Use the debugger.

Comment: Also: you print a spare `' '` at the end of each word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code,

```
  printf("%s", s[i]);
```

is wrong. Change it to

```
 printf("%c", s[i]);
```

as, you're trying to print a `char` value. The conversion specifier for a `char` is `%c`.

Note: Always remember, using wrong conversion specifier will lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, while `scan()`-ing with `%s`, you cannot read the *whole* space-delimited input as a *single* string. From the man page,

> ### %s
>
> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence and the terminating null byte (`'\0'`), which is added automatically. **The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.**

You need to use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to do the job.

That said,

1. Indent your code properly, make it human-readable.
2. Chnage `scanf("%s", s);` to `scanf("99%s", s);` to avoid possible buffer overflow by putting longer input string than 99 `char`s.
3. the proper signature for `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: Yes, It worked after I put gets(s) , thank you soo much

Comment: @Rookie_Coder ___NEVER___ use `gets()`, it's broken. use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: when I put fgets it doesnt compile

Comment: it says, too few arguments to function

Answer (score 3):

Rookie, using **line-oriented** input like `fgets` or `getline` is, in general, the proper way to read a line of text. However, when doing simple splitting on a single character, reading a character at a time can be advantageous.

In your case if your task is to read a sentence up to 100 characters and print the words of the sentence out on separate lines, then there is no reason to read the sentence into an array and store the words. You can simply read/print each character until a space is read, then print a `newline` instead of the space. The reading/printing continues until you reach 100 chars, encounter a `newline` or `EOF`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 100

int main(void) {

    int c = 0;
    size_t n = 0;

    printf ("\n Enter a sentence.\n\n input: ");

    /* read up to 100 characters from stdin, print each word on a line */
    while (n < MAXC && (c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        if (c == ' ')
            printf ("\n");
        else
            printf ("%c", c);
        n++;
    }
    printf ("\n");

    if (n == MAXC) /* read and discard remaining chars in stdin */
        while ((c = getchar ()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

    return 0;

}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getchar_print_nl_space

 Enter a sentence.

 input: This is a sentence to split into words.
This
is
a
sentence
to
split
into
words.
```

**Note:** if you were going to store all characters, up to 100 (meaning 99 chars and 1 null-terminator), you would need to adjust the length check to `n < MAXC - 1` and then null-terminate the array:

```
    char s[MAXC] = {0};

    /* read up to 99 characters from stdin into s */
    while (n < MAXC - 1 && (c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        s[n++] = c;

    s[n] = '\0';        /* null-terminate after last character  */

    if (n == MAXC - 1) /* read and discard remaining chars in stdin */
        while ((c = getchar ()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

You would then repeat the logic checking for a space and printing a `newline` in a `for` loop:

```
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        if (s[c] == ' ')
            printf ("\n");
        else
            printf ("%c", s[c]);
```

Understanding both manner of input, **character-oriented** input and **line-oriented** input will save you time allowing you to match the correct tool to the situation. Here, there is no "more correct" or "less correct" approach, just different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think one more way to do this work in a better way is as following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CHAR 100

int main() {

    char s[100],*c;
    int i = 0;

    scanf("%[^\n]", s);

    //Write your logic to print the tokens of the sentence here.
    for ( c = s; *c != (int)NULL; c++){

        if ( *c == ' '){
            *c = '\n';
        }
    }
    printf("%s",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is the answer.
Program also calculates number of space/char and new line.

http://cprograming-char-operation.blogspot.com/2018/07/for-given-statement-print-word-in-each.html

```
/* Program 1_12 */
/* Count number of line, space and char */
/* Replace a char with specific newline */
/* Add blank space in first input */
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c,nl,nc,ns,nt;
    nl=nc=ns=nt=0;
    int d,r, prevd, prevr;
    printf("Enter which char to replace :: ");

    /* prev is stored before of \n */
    while((d = getchar()) != '\n' && (prevd = d));
    d = prevd;
    printf("Enter word below \n");
    while((c=getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        ++nc;
        if(c==' ')
            ++ns;
        if(c=='\n')
            ++nl;
        if(c=='\t')
            ++nt;
        /* Replace a char with A */
        if(c==d)
            putchar('\n');
        else
            putchar(c);
    }
    printf("total char=%2d, newline=%2d, space=%2d tabs=%2d\n",nc,nl,ns,nt);
    return 0;
}

/* Written by: Prakash Katudia <prakash.katudia@gmail.com> */
```

## gcc ./my_code.c

## ./a.out

Enter which char to replace :: **#space#**

Enter word below

hello how are you
hello

how

are

you

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
     char a[1000];          
     int i,len;                          

     scanf("%[^\n]s",a);
     len=strlen(a);

     for(i=0;i<len;i++)
     {
         if(a[i] !=' ')
         {
             printf("%c", a[i]);  
             printf("\n");
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In order for the answer to be useful to the OP, please indicate what you have changed and _why_.